# Get-WMIObject fails when run AsJob

Tags: powershell

It's a simple question, but it's stumped me.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$jobs = @()
$jobs += Get-WmiObject `
-Authentication 6 `
-ComputerName 'serverName' `
-Query 'Select * From IISWebServerSetting' `
-Namespace 'root/microsoftiisv2' `
-EnableAllPrivileges `
-Credential $cred `
-Impersonation 4 `
-AsJob

$joblist = Wait-Job -Job $jobs -Timeout 60

foreach ($job in $jobs)
{
    if ($job.State -eq "Completed")
    {
        $app = Receive-Job -Job $job
        $app
    } else {
        ("Job not completed: " + $job.Name + "@" + $job.State + ". Reason:" + $job.ChildJobs[0].JobStateInfo.Reason)
        Remove-Job -Job $job -Force
    }
}
```

The query succeeds when run directly and fails when run -AsJob.

```
Reason:System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.
```

I've jiggered with -Impersonation, -Credentials, -Authority, and -EnableAllPrivileges to no useful effect. It appears I'm overlooking something fundamental. Why is my Powershell prompt allowed to connect to the remote server, but my child process denied?

Comment: Grrrrrrr-gle >-/ The code runs fine when run from a server. Preliminary guess: There's a firewall somewhere intercepting my traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the remote computer and the computer you are running this on configured for PowerShell V2 remoting? If you look at the help for get-wmiobject it states the following:

> Note: To use this parameter with
>   remote computers, the local and remote
>   computers must be configured for
>   remoting. Additionally, you must start
>   Windows PowerShell by using the "Run
>   as administrator" option in Windows V
>           ista and later versions of Windows,. For more information, see
>   about_Remote_Requirements.

Comment: Ah. I see now. When I was able to connect directly, I assumed the issue was authentication somehow. Actually, PowerShell is trying to run the command remotely. I cannot Enter-PSSession on any of the 200+ boxes I'm working against, and I cannot configure Remoting on them. I think I'll batch my requests and run them as simultaneous, multiple local sessions. Same benefits and works within my assigned environment. Thanks, James.

Answer (score 0):

The "Access Denied" you are seeing is actually from DCOM.  -AsJob and WMI use a better, more efficent form of WMI remoting known as asynchronous remoting.  Because of this, you have to do some additional firewall configuration changes.  In particular, I believe you need to "Allow Remote Administration" in the Windows Firewall UI.

This document on MSDN describes the setting in greater detail:

[Connecting to WMI Thru Windows Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389286%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks "Start". I'm 99% sure, though, Windows Firewall is disabled on this W2k3 server. It's disabled by default (per your article) and I believe we have a policy of keeping internal firewalls turned off. I can check on Monday, but I don't believe this is it.